# Getting attribute error while using pillow library

Tags: python

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw, ImageFont


class WatermarkApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Watermark App")

        # Create Widgets
        self.upload_button = tk.Button(root, text="Upload Image", command=self.upload_image)
        self.upload_button.pack()

        self.watermark_text_entry = tk.Entry(root)
        self.watermark_text_entry.pack()

        self.add_watermark_button = tk.Button(root, text="Add Watermark", command=self.add_watermark)
        self.add_watermark_button.pack()

        # Initialize variables
        self.image_path = None
        self.image = None
        self.image_label = None

    def upload_image(self):
        self.image_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image files", "*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.bmp")])

        if self.image_path:
            self.image = Image.open(self.image_path)
            self.image.thumbnail((400, 400))  # Resize image to fit in GUI

            # Display the image on the GUI
            self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
            if self.image_label:
                self.image_label.destroy()
            self.image_label = tk.Label(root, image=self.image)
            self.image_label.pack()

    def add_watermark(self):
        if self.image_path and self.image:
            watermark_text = self.watermark_text_entry.get()

            if watermark_text:
                watermark = Image.new("RGBA", (self.image.width(), self.image.height()), (0, 0, 0, 0))
                draw = ImageDraw.Draw(watermark)
                font = ImageFont.truetype("arialbd.ttf", 36)  # Change font as needed

                text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(watermark_text, font=font)
                x = self.image.width() - text_width - 10
                y = self.image.height() - text_height - 10

                draw.text((x, y), watermark_text, font=font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 128))
                watermarked_image = Image.alpha_composite(self.image, watermark)

                self.image_label.configure(image=None)  # Clear previous image
                self.image_label.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(watermarked_image)
                self.image_label.configure(image=self.image_label.image)
            else:
                print("Please enter a watermark text.")


root = tk.Tk()
app = WatermarkApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried debugging the code but I am just getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ajay2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\pycharm\pythonProjectwatermark app\main.py", line 49, in add_watermark
    text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(watermark_text, font=font)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ImageDraw' object has no attribute 'textsize'
```

If anyone can check my code and please give me the solution

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing or debugging service - I'd suggest taking the [tour]. If you want a good answer, you'll need to provide a some details on what you're trying to achieve, what exactly you've tried, a [mre], etc.. For more information, you might want to look at [ask] :)

Comment: You have everything you need in traceback. Draw class doesn't have textsize method that you are trying to call.

Comment: This question is currently one of the top results on Google when searching for this exception. I don't blame you guys for not answering it, but they pointed out the issue and they're getting the typical "Do better" treatment from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip list` to find what version of Pillow you have. In my case, I had pillow 9.4.0. However it was recommended by this thread https://bugs.launchpad.net/tacker/+bug/2026345 to upgrade to pillow 9.5.0 or higher.

I used 9.5.0 and it resolved the error (which was occurring on my Ubuntu machine, but not on windows).

`pip install --upgrade pillow==9.5.0`

Note if you're using a requirements.txt you should set the version there and use `pip install -r requirements.txt`